# Why did "s" use to look like "f"?

Tags: english, writing-systems

Example: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Houghton_EC65.M6427P.1667aa_-_Paradise_Lost%2C_1667.jpg

> Paradife loft.

There is no way that I can ever read that as:

> Paradise lost.

The most bizarre part is that the smaller print on the same page says

> Dunftons

Does this mean:

> Dunstons

Or is it literally an "f" in that case? And why does it end with an actual "s" if "s" looks like "f"?

Please clarify this.

Answer (score 9):

That <ſ> shape of "s" is called "long *s*": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s

> The long *s* was derived from the old Roman cursive medial *s*. When the distinction between majuscule (uppercase) and minuscule (lowercase) letter forms became established, toward the end of the eighth century, it developed a more vertical form.

The long *s* is used only at the beginning of a word or inside a word, never as the word-final letter, and it is graphically distinct from "f" in that it either has no horizontal bar at all, or the bar is only on the left side of the vertical stroke, while with "f" the horizontal bar crosses the vertical line.

In Germany, until 1945 when most printed matter was in the [Fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) typeset, the long *s* was always used. Even now in the German language there is a trace of the long *s* — the letter [ß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) (*Eszett* or *scharfes S* in German) is a ligature of ſs.

Comment: It pretty much disappears from English printed after about 1800; OCR from books printed before this date has numerous mistaken `f` errors.

Comment: @jlawler - Here's a rare case on the 20th cent. usage of `ſ`. On [these banknotes](https://thumbs.worthpoint.com/zoom/images2/360/1015/17/germany-lithuania-kowno-20-50-100_360_df0e9a603ec94ab8970631901da948a5.jpg) issued in 1918 in Kowno (now Kaunas, Lithuania), the text is in antiqua, but the Latvian part ( upper image, right side) uses `ſ` for [z] and `ſ` crossed diagonally for [s] (diagonally like Polish `ł`). The bold lowercase Latvian text in the modern orthography is "Aizdevu kases zīme". Note that both Lithuanian and German, which are also present on the banknote, don't use any long s.

Comment: @jlawler - The Unicode for that letter is 1E9C ẜ  latin small letter long s with diagonal stroke: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EA%9E%A8

Comment: The Nazis decided in 1941 that blackletter was henceforth to be seen as *Judenlettern* so I would wager most printed German matter post-1941 was already antiqua.

Comment: @Jan - Really? Why then the _NS-Frauenwarte_, a Nazi magazine which had the status of the only National Socialist party approved magazine for women, was [printed in Fraktur](https://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/diglit/frauenwarte1944/0037/image) until the very end of its publication in 1944?

Comment: @YellowSky I didn’t actually check any publications of the war years, but the point stands that the [party decision on *Judenlettern* was in 1941](http://ligaturix.de/bormann.htm).